# Slanted math mode numbers in caption

Tags: fonts, captions, memoir, slanted

Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\captiontitlefont{\slshape}     % All captions slanted

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Flowchart of a gradient-based optimization algorithm. $ \Delta \alpha_i^{(k)} $ is the change of $ \alpha_i $ from iteration $ k $ to iteration $ k+1 $.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

resulting in this figure (without the red line):

[image: example_figure]

The caption is slated, but numbers in math mode are not. In my opinion it looks weird that the '+1' is not slanted. It can be fixed (badly) by moving it outside math mode, but then the spacing is clearly wrong.

How do I make the entire caption slanted, but with variables like 'k' staying in math mode font?

Comment: It is standard convention: italic letters, upright numbers in math.

Comment: The easiest option is to use `\mathit{k+1}`, but then you'll probably complain that the operator `+` is not slanted.

Comment: `\mathit{1}` looks weird

Comment: @Werner: You are absolutely correct. ;)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Standard convention is not necessarily best. Also, I think this is a matter of taste.

Comment: "standard convention" is a tradition of centuries, ever since math has been printed.  it is specified in books informing printers how to typeset math.  for the same reason, delimiters (parentheses, brackets, braces) are also set upright in math.  if you submit this for publication, it will be changed by a trained copyeditor.

Comment: @barbarabeeton:  I think it looks like the numbers are emphasized, which is not my intention. Maybe normalfont captions are worth considering.

Comment: your observation about emphasis is reasonable.  i've never seen italicized captions in any math book or journal article, and maybe that has something to do with it.  on the other hand, theorems *are* italicized, but the numerals in math are always upright (and careful publishers will also set "text" numerals, e.g. for dates, upright as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think these things are perhaps very sparse, so I'd suggest defining commands to solve your problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\captiontitlefont{\slshape}     % All captions slanted
\newcommand{\slplus}{\mathbin{\mbox{\slshape +}}}
\newcommand{\slone}{\mbox{\slshape 1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Flowchart of a gradient-based optimization algorithm. 
    $ \Delta \alpha_i^{(k)} $ is the change of $ \alpha_i $ from iteration $ k $ to iteration $ k \slplus \slone $.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a great solution (to a problem that shouldn't be solved). The reason I got to it was slanted headers that contain the chapter and/or section titles. Can it be somehow applied there?

Comment: @Bolpat: Yes, but it depends on many things, like the packages you might be using or the `\documentclass`. Can you provide access to a MWE?